# Enabling recaptcha on coupon code in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, recaptcha, coupon

I am trying to use a reCAPTCHA button on the coupon field for the shopping cart in WooCommerce.

I have added code in my theme functions.php file and in cart.php template file, to add the reCAPTCHA, disable the Apply Coupon button and then on a successful reCAPTCHA, verify with the server and then enable the Apply Coupon button.

However, I seem to have an issue where the AJAX call doesn't occur.

Code in functions.php file:

```
// ReCAPTCHA verification callback
function verify_recaptcha_callback() {
    $recaptcha_response = sanitize_text_field($_POST['recaptchaResponse']);
    $secret_key = 'MY_SECRET_KEY'; // Replace with your actual secret key

    $verification_response = wp_safe_remote_post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', array(
        'body' => array(
            'secret'   => $secret_key,
            'response' => $recaptcha_response,
        ),
    ));

    if (is_wp_error($verification_response)) {
        wp_send_json(array('success' => false, 'error' => 'Verification failed'));
    }

    $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($verification_response);
    $response_data = json_decode($response_body);

    if ($response_data->success) {
        wp_send_json(array('success' => true));
    } else {
        wp_send_json(array('success' => false, 'error' => 'Verification failed'));
    }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_verify_recaptcha', 'verify_recaptcha_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_verify_recaptcha', 'verify_recaptcha_callback');
```

Code in my cart.php:

```
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="actions">
                 <?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
                        <div class="coupon">
                         <!-- Coupon code input and Apply Coupon button here -->
<label for="coupon_code" class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                            <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
                            <button type="submit" class="button<?php echo esc_attr( wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '' ); ?>" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
                         <!-- Add reCAPTCHA widget here -->
                         <div id="coupon-recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY_SITE_KEY" data-callback="onRecaptchaSuccess"></div>
                                    <!-- Place the script here -->
                                    <script>
                                        function enableApplyCouponButton() {
                                            var applyCouponButton = document.querySelector('button[name="apply_coupon"]');
                                            if (applyCouponButton) {
                                                applyCouponButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
                                            }
                                        }

                                        function disableApplyCouponButton() {
                                            var applyCouponButton = document.querySelector('button[name="apply_coupon"]');
                                            if (applyCouponButton) {
                                                applyCouponButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
                                            }
                                        }

                                        function onRecaptchaSuccess(response) {
                                            console.log('reCAPTCHA succeeded');
        
                                            // Send the reCAPTCHA response to the server for verification
                                            jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {
                                                action: 'verify_recaptcha',
                                                recaptchaResponse: response,
                                            }, function(data) {
                                                if (data.success) {
                                                   enableApplyCouponButton();
                                               } else {
                                                   console.error('reCAPTCHA verification failed');
                                                }
                                           });
                                        }

                                        // Disable the button initially
                                        disableApplyCouponButton();

                                    </script>


                         </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                 <!-- Update cart button and other actions here -->

                 <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart', 'woocommerce-cart-nonce' ); ?>
             </td>
            </tr>
```

I was expecting to see the ajax call in the network but the fact that it isnt there makes me think it isnt working. I am not sure how to solve.

Comment: First, you should insert your code via a PHP function hooked in `woocommerce_cart_coupon` action hook, instead of overriding cart.php template. Always try to use available hooks first.
Now in your code you are disabling the update button on start, **which is wrong** as this button **allows to update also cart item quantities.** You should enable reCAPTCHA only when user enters on the coupon field (focus in). Now, I don't really catch the utility to add a reCAPTCHA on a coupon field.

Comment: The cart.php I have updated is in child theme folder rather than original. Also, this code isnt disabling the cart update, just the apply coupon button. The reason for recatpcha is to stop bots using brute force technique to find coupons. I've actually got this working now, the issue was that the theme I was using doesnt have ajaxurl redefined, I added code to my functions.php to define it and now it works

Comment: Of course, if you override a template, it's obvious that the edited template has to be located in your child theme as recommended by WooCommerce. But templates are updated on time to time, so it's better (recommended) to use hooks at first (that is a professional developer behavior). Now, if you get that working, good!